# Proving two triangles are congruent using SAS, ASA, SSS, and SSA

Tags: geometry

[image]

Given $\angle A \cong \angle EDF$ and $AB \cong DE$, which pair of corresponding parts is needed to prove $\triangle ABC \cong \triangle DEF$

a) By SAS:

We need $AC\cong DF$

b) By ASA:

We need $\angle CBA \cong \angle FEB$

c) By SSS:

We need $CB \cong FE$ and $AC \cong DF$

d) By SSA:

Not sure if this is a trick question since SSA isn't a test that can be used for congruence of two triangles. If it could be used then we would need $CE\cong FE$

e) AAS:

$\angle ACB \cong \angle DFE$

Comment: Please include a shape in questions like these.

Comment: @Goku so sorry i forgot to do that! I just updated